# Automatically create a default set of posts for each new registered user

Tags: posts, users

Is there a plugin, or a way to automatically create a set of default posts for a new user when they register? I suspect that the answer might be to hook into the existing wordpress events - can anybody suggest a way to get started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of `user_register` and `wp_insert_post` should work fine:

```
add_action('user_register', 'create_postset');

function create_postset($user_id) {
    // userinfo
    $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
    // Create post objects
    $post_1 = array(
        'post_title' => '1st post created for ' . $user_info->user_login,
        'post_content' => 'Lorem Ipsum',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => $user_id
    );
    $post_2 = array(
        'post_title' => '2nd post created for ' . $user_info->user_login,
        'post_content' => 'Lorem Ipsum',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => $user_id
    );

    // Insert posts into the database
    wp_insert_post($post_1);
    wp_insert_post($post_2);
}
```

Comment: The OP already knows that hooks are needed. This barely expands upon that. Can you provide some plausible sample code to demonstrate _how_ you would do this?

Comment: It seemed like he just had no idea which keywords he should try to find a hook that fits his needs. So in that specific case I guess he would have been sucessful without a codesample. But nevertheless it's always quite cool to have a functional copy&paste snippet, so I just edited my answer.

Comment: that may be true but the site policy is to provide answers that help the general population and not just the OP. That means more complete answers than might strictly be necessary along with code if possible. Your original answer, by the way, was flagged by the automated system as being "low quality". Now it would not be.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, many thanks. I think that this is the first time I've not been able to find a plugin that does what I want!